# GET Method Parsing

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-parser

Can someone help me better understand this code better.

```
// request method is GET
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
url += "?" + paramString;
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Mainly i just need help figuring out the URL part.

> url += "?" + paramString;

how can i better customize that part of the code?

On customization i want to take my current url

> academic_programs_xml/oncampus-departments.xml

and change it to

> academic_programs_xml/oncampus-associates.xml

my thoughts are that you can take the url for the location

> academic_programs_xml/

then add the param to the url then add .xml

something like this maybe?

> url += paramString + ".xml";

Comment: http://jodd.org/doc/http.html

Comment: could you be a bit clear about what you mean by "customize that part"

Comment: On customization i want to take my current url 

academic_programs_xml/oncampus-departments.xml

and change it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here we are adding parameters to a URL
Lets take an example.

```
Base URL : www.example.com/index.php
```

If we want to add the parameter { search = hello }

we would do so like this

```
Param URL : www.example.com/index.php?search=hello
```

Basically, anything after the ? mark in the end of the URL, are key value
pair parameters.

Now back to your code, You create a key-value pair string of parameters in the code

```
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
```

Then you are appending it to the URL after adding a question mark with the code

```
url += "?" + paramString;
```

I hope that's clear.

Comment: This is perfect! thanks it actually answered my question perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

On figuring out:
The "?" marks the end of the URI path section and the start of the query string. The Query string is usually used to encode parameters e.g. during a call to an web service.

On customizing, it is not clear what you mean.